# Dynamically adding values in activiti enum form type

Tags: activiti

Can we dynamically add enum values to activiti enum form property type?
I am aware we can statically add form properties as :

```
<activiti:formProperty id="vacationApproved" name="Do you approve this vacation" type="enum" required="true">
  <activiti:value id="true" name="Approve" />
  <activiti:value id="false" name="Reject" />
</activiti:formProperty>
```

Instead of statically supplying values using activiti:value tag, i would like to achieve the same using expressions. I supplied an expression thinking it would resolve. HOwever, When the form is retrieved, there were no values in the form property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the OOTB forms aren't much flexible, they are for simple use cases. for more complex forms try extending the forms framework or simply use form-key that can be later on used to search for your custom form definitions (in form of json, xml, etc.). once you have your definition, you can work on UI based on it.